# Can I delete files from "Windows" folder in Windows Server 2016 using C# (MVC or Core)?

Tags: c#, web, delete-file, windows-server-2016

In windows server 2016, I create a text file inside "Windows" folder for some reasons, and in special cases I need to delete it from my website which is built in C# MVC, is there any way to do that using C# (MVC or Core)? I know that it is illogical but I need that if applicable.

Comment: Sure you can do this - you just need to grant your website Application Pool user the according privileges but this is a horrible security risk, no matter what reasons you have for storing files accessed by web there.

Comment: This is related to file managing dependencies. If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: It is very bad idea to create work files in `Windows` folder especially on Windows Server (not desktop OS). There are other locations for any kind of files - private, public, software specific, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for your solution is fairly simple, yes it is indeed possible to remove a Windows file or folder. However, this is costly! Allowing an application to have Administrator permissions can lead to malicious behaviors. Such as UAC Bypassing from other malware.

All you need to do in order to delete that file programming using C# is to first off run your application with administrator rights. Here's source the code for it:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
public class Program {
   public static void Main() {
      String myPath = @"<DRIVE_LETTER>:\Windows\<FILENAME>"; // E.g: @"C:\Windows\MyText.txt";
      try{ // For stability purposes,
          File.Delete(myPath);
      } catch (IOException ERROR){ // If any errors occurs, it will print it out!
          Console.WriteLine(ERROR.Message);
      }
   }
}
```

Documentation for Permission(s) Risks: [Risks of Admin Rights](https://www.greenhousedata.com/blog/should-you-allow-windows-users-to-have-administrative-rights)

Documentation for File.Delete: [File.Delete(String) Method C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.delete?view=netcore-3.1)